# Как через браузер выполнить команду в терминале Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, firefox

Есть какой-либо способ через адресную строку `firefox` выполнить команду в bash-e? 
Или запустить скрипт с параметрами.
Например, в адресной строке я ввожу:
run_script `test1`
и у меня запускается скрипт `/usr/local/script.sh` с параметром `test1`.

У меня уже получилось запустить скрипт `file:///usr/local/script.sh` и в настройках `firefox` выбрать "все файлы `*.sh` открывать с помощью `/bin/bash`". 
А вот как мне передать этому скрипту переменные?

Comment: А вот такой вариант не подойдет? http://paradoxxxzero.github.io/2014/02/28/butterfly.html P.S. Это неправильный путь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь существующим незадействованным протоколом. список — на странице `about:preferences#applications` (или через меню `preferences → applications`).

например, протоколом *irc*. в колонке *action* напротив него откройте список и выберите *use other*, а в открывшемся диалоге укажите на созданный вами скрипт-обработчик.

теперь, если в браузере набрать `irc://123&456?word/letter` или «щёлкнуть» по ссылке с этим адресом (вроде `<a href="irc://123&456?word/letter">нажмите сюда</a>`), то именно такую строку (`irc://123&456?word/letter`) ваш скрипт и получит первым параметром.

что дальше делать с этой строкой — уже на полное ваше усмотрение. можете, например, в какой-нибудь файл записывать:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1" >> /tmp/clicks.log
```

p.s. не забудьте биты исполняемости поставить на файл со скриптом:

```
$ chmod +x /путь/к/файлу
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ с детальным описанием.
Все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Пишем простенький веб-эмулятор терминала на PHP. Посмотрите [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139878/).

Comment: немного не то.
Конечный пользователь который будет работать в firefox - оператор колл-центра, и запустившийся терминал в браузере введет его в ступор:)

Comment: оттуда можно вырвать контекст передачи команд

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 0):

Напиши обработчик протокола.
Вместо передачи напрямую башу передай эту ссылку в скрипт, где строку вида `file:///script.sh?q=123?w` преобразуем в `bash /script.sh -q 123 -w`